# Where does QGIS save the processing log for a specific project?

Tags: qgis-3, log

After updating to current stable version (3.4.12 Madeira at time of writing), when opening a project, the processing log as described in https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/processing/log.html is not accessible any more through the previously visible "Processing" tab. I would like to access the processing history *of a specific project* to review it.

This already happened to me when I updated from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2, although I wasn't certain about it back then, because I hadn't paid attention specifically to it, since I didn't expect to lose the processing history.

(I handed in my project with an incomplete history file. Nobody noticed because they didn't run it, but, you know, it's bad and not contributing to reproducible science. For my next project, if I update to a newer version of QGIS, I'd like to be able to provide a full processing history :D )

Comment: Are you sure that the Processing log is kept for a specific project? I though it as only during the QGIS Desktop session. Can you add a screnshoot about a project having a previous history, what you call "incomplete history file". Thanks

Comment: @etrimaille I am not sure at all. In fact, now that you ask about it, I doubt it. I expected it, because it seems weird the log file wouldn't be kept per project, but it seems that's not how it's done, I guess.

Comment: It's in the plan to add some kind of processing history in the project metadata panel, in the last tabs about "history". But this hasn't been done yet. So for now, except with a plugin that I don't know, the Processing history is just in the current session. So I'm not sure why you talked that you lost the history when migrating QGIS version.

Comment: @etrimaille you mean to say that when I close QGIS, the processing history is erased? That doesn't fit with my experience. The processing history of processes executed a few months back was still in the history, but got lost after the update.

Comment: Sorry, indeed you have the history on your QGIS session (which have been launch on this specific computer) if you click on the small clock on the Processing toolbox panel or from the Processing menu. This is reading the file `processing/processing.log` file in your profile (`Settings`, `Profile` and `Open active profile`). Did you get a new profile maybe?

Comment: @etrimaille Ok, thx, found it. It's at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing`. This is the file I was looking for in the question. In `...\profiles\`, there is only `default` and `defaultQuickOSM`. Unfortunately, the history file doesn't have any older entries than 2018-10-25, but that's a different story. I didn't make a new profile, but it might have been purged when updating from Bonn to Madeira. I don't recall in detail. Anyways, please add an answer summing up this comment thread so we get an actual answer to the question ;)

Comment: `defaultQuickOSM` is a profile you created You can remove it if you want, it won't be displayed in QGIS UI after that. So the history file in `default` contains your history? It shouldn't be purged. The history file belongs to your profile on this computer.

Comment: @etrimaille the history file in `default` contains my history. It doesn't contain entries older than 2018-10-25, but it might not have anything to do with QGIS. I finally got a hold of my notebook and my first hand notes (GIS related, that is) on this project actually date back to the same date, so, that seems ok. Where the rest went... well... I might have fiddled with some file locations in general. I'll find them, no biggie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments we wrote above.

QGIS is only saving the Processing history in the current QGIS profile, so on a single computer, not per project.

- Open your profile folder with `Settings`, `Profile` and `Open active profile`
- Go in `processing` folder.
- Open `processing.log`.

So you could get an empty history if:

- you created a new profile on the same computer
- you did the processing algorithm on another computer

There is a plan in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/91 about Metadata Management to include this Processing history somehow in `Project` `Properties` `Metadata` `History` and/or in the equivalent panel in `Layer Properties` `Metadata` `History`

Comment: I am running a lot of Processing stuff and there is no log file there. Does it need to be activated somewhere? I found no option in the QGIS options.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with what version processing history was moved, but at least since 3.28, history is loged in **`user-history.db`** file. You can find it in user directory:

[image]

you can open it in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: thx for the additional (up to date) answer. The original question was about a processing history on a per-project basis. Of course, a workaround could be to create a separate user for each individual project, but that seems cumbersome. Let's hope for the future. Maybe I should mention it at the next user conference and see what the more seasoned professionals have to say about it.