# Documenting workflow and processing in QGIS-project

Tags: qgis, qgs

I want to include a documentation about the steps I undertook to create a QGIS-project to be able to understand how my data was prepared and processed, which steps I performed in QGIS. I'm not sure about the right place where this should be done. Looking to the Project Properties Dialog, section Metadata Properties, there is a history tab. However, the documentation does not really explain it:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#project-properties

Is this tab ment to get a description of the workflow or is there another place for it in a QGIS project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More clues than definitive answer to the part as I'm not sure there is "one" good answer here to your question

If QGIS 3.14 and using Model designer, "Allow creation of group boxes in models" https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#allow-creation-of-group-boxes-models and "Comments in Processing Models" https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#comments-processing-models are ways to help document your processing.

I'm wondering why do you want to document within QGIS? Formatting is limited in metadata description. I would maybe use an HTML frame in a dedicated layout instead of using description.
You should also look at [Where does QGIS save the processing log for a specific project?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338970/where-does-qgis-save-the-processing-log-for-a-specific-project) that give some hints about processing history management in QGIS.